# How can I stop the panel from showing on an external projector/monitor?

Tags: 11.04, unity, multiple-monitors, display, monitor

In Ubuntu 10.10 (and possibly previous versions), when I connected my laptop to an external source (monitor/projector) and set it not to clone my desktop the display on the external source would not show the (gnome-)panel (just a full-screen desktop with no icons).

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 11.04 (using Unity) when I now connect the external source has the panel on there. Is there any way to revert to the previous behaviour in 11.04?

Answer (score 1):

You can (for now) choose "Ubuntu Classic" when logging in - and, although this won't give you Unity, it is a workaround for your problem.

*(From what I've seen, Unity currently has major problems with multi-screen displays).*

Comment: Can you update your answer to match the current situation?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible (currently) in Ubuntu when using Unity as your desktop environment. However, you can install Gnome-panel and login to "Gnome Fallback Mode" to get this setup, or use XFCE or LXDE.